# Flutter Retrieve data from InputField (InternationalPhoneNumberInput)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

```
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: InternationalPhoneNumberInput(onInputChanged: (value) {}),
              )
```

Simple question for those who know Flutter, how do I retrieve the phone number entered into the  PhoneNumberInput field?

Answer (score 0):

you have to define a an empty string variable and store the retrieved value in it:

```html
String _internationalPhoneNumber = '';

      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: InternationalPhoneNumberInput(onInputChanged: (value) {
                setState(()=> _internationalPhoneNumber = value);
                
                print(_internationalPhoneNumber);
                }),
              )
```

Comment: does not work, the value for internationalphonenumber reverts back to original value (i.e. an empty string).